# What is pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd, and How to set it up on SageMaker?

Tags: error-handling, amazon-sagemaker, python-tesseract

**Error Says:**

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/'

when setting up pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd from PyTesseract Module, I gave the location of where the module is installed.

1. What is this tesseract_cmd?
2. How to set it up on AWS SageMaker?
3. Is there any other way to extract text from images other than PyTesseract?
4. Why is it showing me PermissionError when I have the access?

Comment: Same issue, did u get the solution.